# Sample in R a category with multiple levels and take a specific sample size from each category

Tags: r, random, dplyr

I have the following dataset

it contains 3 character variables (A,B,C).

Variable A consists of 13 levels and i want to take a random sample of size n=30 in each category.
The final dataset I want to contain all the samples in rows and the suited B.

I tried

```
data%>%
  group_by(B)%>%
  sample_n(size=30,replace = TRUE)
```

but it didn't work.Any help ?

Comment: Can you be explain what "didn't work" means? (Error, wrong number of samples, ... ?)

Comment: It samples the same ID and not different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your data, some groups you created (like DRH) has less than 30 observations. Since you passed the `replace=TRUE` argument, R duplicates if there is less than 30 observations. You can basicaly remove the argument (while keeping only greater than 30 sample groups) or follow this way;

```
grouped_data <- data %>%
group_by(GEAR) %>%
mutate(size=n())


grouped_data %>%
filter(size>=30) %>%
sample_n(size=30,replace = TRUE) %>%
ungroup %>%
select(-size) -> part_1

grouped_data %>%
filter(size<30) %>%
ungroup %>%
select(-size) -> part_2
```

I filtered the groups whose sample size greater than 30 then took random 30 observations from each of them in `part_1`. `part_2` includes the groups whose sample size less than 30.